# entropy in txt file

Tags: python

I have a text file with numbers in it as follows:

```
1231313123123123
1432423432535345
3532523452345345
1231423432453455
3434535345345345
3452353453253453
```

all the lines are the same length, I want to calculate entropy on each line and have output as:

```
2.64234234
2.65464564
2.35355435
etc.
```

Right now with this piece of code I have gives me entropy to be the same, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import math

def H(data):
  if not data:
    return 0
  entropy = 0
  for x in range(256):
    p_x = float(data.count(chr(x)))/len(data)
    if p_x > 0:
      entropy += - p_x*math.log(p_x, 2)
  return entropy

failas = open('text.txt', 'r')
for row in failas:
        print H('failas')
```

Comment: Since you have 10 unique digits per character, shouldn't you be using a base of 10 in your log? e.g. entropy += - p_x*math.log(p_x, 10)

Comment: FWIW the code is apparently copy/paste from http://blog.dkbza.org/2007/05/scanning-data-for-entropy-anomalies.html

Answer (score 10):

```
failas = open('text.txt', 'r')
for row in failas:
    print H(row)
```

Comment: Or perhaps just `for row in open('text.txt')`?

Comment: Or `with open('text.txt') as failas:`

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you meant `print H(row)`.

Answer (score 1):

All of the above, plus you probably don't want to include the `\n` at end of each line in the entropy calculation. Use `H(row.rstrip('\n'))`

You can answer a lot of your own questions by examining the data that is being tosssed around by your code. In this case, inserting `print repr(data)` after the line `def H(data):` would have shown you what the problem was straight away.